# For React component with input elements, The events are not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, events, element

i've a simple react component with some input elements. No matter what I cannot get any of the event to get triggered.

```
<input
                value={this.state.amount}
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                onChange={ () => {console.log('some message');}}
                onBlur={this.handleAmountChange}
                className="amount"
                dir="ltr"
                type="tel"
                autoComplete="off"
                autoFocus={true}
              />
```

What could be the possible reasons.

Comment: Here is an example that is working just fine with your source code (changed into a functional component though): https://codesandbox.io/s/7yk0y09wo6

Comment: Can you please provide more context around your component and what you are seeing, from this input alone there doesn't appear to be any issues.

Comment: I can see all the UI changes as to if I give value ={10}, it is reflected. But only the events are not getting triggered. There seems to be no issue with code I've implemented. What could be the other possible causes which I can look into?

Comment: @Jeny nothing about this code looks problematic to me. Could you please add more context, such as the React component this input is a part of?

Comment: Looks like the code is using Server Side Rendering. So the events are not firing. New to the concept. Any more information would help.